# Using du to estimate amount of space for files in list file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got a directory structure which looks like this:

```
/here/are/my/files/
```

My files are named by some convention, let's say:

```
myfile_0001.txt
myfile_0001.bin
myfile_0001.xls
...(few other extensions)
myfile_0567.txt
myfile_0567.bin
myfile_0567.xls
... (few other extensions)
```

And so on. Extensions may change, or there may be too many of them for a label `myfile_xxxx` to care about it.
On the other hand, I've got file `list.txt` with entries:

```
myfile_0001
myfile_1234
myfile_0204
... (label number is irregular).
```

What I want to do is to estimate amount of space of all file families (that is, myfile_xxxx* - all extensions for a given file label), that are included in `list.txt` (and only for them).
How i was doing it so far:

```
file_list=$(for entry in $( cat list.txt); do ls /here/are/my/files/$entry* ; done)
du -shc $file_list
```

(It could be combined in one line without `$file_list` variable, but it looks more readable for me).
Can I do it in one line with only `du` command, with something like

```
du -c "/here/are/my/files/$(cat list.txt)* | tail -1
```

(It dosen't work, but I would like to get something in similar form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
du -hs -c $(for line in `cat list.txt`; do ls $line; done) | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will print only the filesize in human readable format

EDIT:
If you want to provide a static path that is not privided in the list.txt you can do

```
du -hs -c $(for line in `cat list.txt`; do ls /path/to/files/${line}; done) | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you want all files with the sufix in the list.txt do

```
du -hs -c $(for line in `cat list.txt`; do ls /path/to/files/${line}*; done) | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you dont want human readable format remove "-hs" from the command

Comment: The last one seems legit!